# Jquery UI autocomplete widget : Get the current ui.item selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using JqueryUI autocomplete widget.

Is it possible to retrieve the current ui.item selected without store anything durring the onSelect event?

Something like `$('#selector').val().ui.item;` ?

Comment: When are you trying to get the selected item? `focus`? `select`?

Comment: After a button click. I have some custom information (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data) in the ui.item object that I would like retrieve. It is possible that no onSelect event occured if the user doesn't select a new data

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and came across this answer [jquery autocomplete - get selected item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8325220/jquery-autocomplete-get-selected-item).

So the answer seems to be, "No, it's not possible", at least OOTB. You need to code some logic to store the selectedItem in the callbacks.

Hope it helps clarify this issue while providing a different way to achieve what you want.